# Why i can't compare 3 arrays at the same time?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 3 arrays called `a`, `b` and `c`.

I compare them to check if their same indexes has same value.

If i compare like this it doesn't work.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (a[i] === b[i] === c[i]) {
     console.log("Matched")
    }
 }
```

But if i do like this, it works.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   if (a[i] === b[i] && a[i] === c[i] && b[i] === c[i]) {
      console.log("Matched")
    }
 }
```

So, Why?

[**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/vepoyexigo/edit?js,console)

Comment: because JavaScript does not know that is what you want to do. It is doing `a[i] === (b[i] === c[i])` with order of operations. So it is `a[i]=== true|false`

Comment: Because `a[i] === b[i] === c[i]` does not do what you think it should, it is interpreted as `a[i] === (b[i] === c[i])`

Comment: if `a[i] === b[i] && a[i] === c[i]` then the `b[i] === c[i]` test will always true and redundant, you can remove it.

Comment: All the answers about comparing a boolean value (true/false) against an array value are technically correct.  But there should also be mention that the javascript interpreter has to tokenize the code and process them through regular expressions to evaluate an appropriate order of operations.  You will not understand WHY true != c[i] without learning about interpreters and compilers.

Comment: @epascarello, no, please check `true === 1 === 1`. the real expression is like `(a[i] === b[i]) === c[i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `a[i] === b[i] === c[i]` does not do what you think it should: it is interpreted as

**`(a[i] === b[i]) === c[i]`**

which then translates to `true === c[i]` or `false === c[i]` based on the first comparison result.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = [1, 2, 3];
var c = [1, true, 3];

for (var i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
  if (a[i] === b[i] === c[i]) {
    console.log('Match found at index: ' + i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Something interesting happens when you remove one `=` from the `===`

```js
a=[1,2,3],b=[1,2,3],c=[1,2,3];

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (a[i] == b[i] == c[i]) {
         console.log("Matched")
        }
    }

    //Matched
```

It works! But why? 
That's because there is a distinction between `==` and `===` in javascript.

With `===` it must be exact. So like the other answers are saying: `a[i] === (b[i] === c[i])`, which then translates to `a[i] === true` or `a[i] === false` - meaning it must literally be `true` or `false`, not just equate to that.

If you use `==` then it doesn't have to be exact, it only has to equate to `true` or `false` or as we usually say `truthy` or `falsy`.

Note: I don't advise to use the method with `==` in this case as this is only to make a point. It's best to separate them out and use `===`. If you try other combinations you will notice matches on arrays that shouldn't match. That's because they are matching `truthy`

See this code:

```js
a=[0,5,7],b=[1,3,8],c=[0,2,9];

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (a[i] == b[i] == c[i]) {
         console.log("Matched")
        }
    }
```

Now what if they everything was literally `true` and you used `===`? It also matches.

```js
a=[true],b=[true],c=[true];

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (a[i] === b[i] === c[i]) {
         console.log("Matched")
        }
    }
```

Comment: but if a,b and c are `[0,1,2]` the match will not occurs! While a = [0,1,2] and b=[1,1,2] and c = [0,1,2] will be evaluated as equals array!

Comment: @Eineki it still matches if all are [0,1,2]. But yes, it's not the best way to match because there will be bugs as in the one you just stated.

Comment: Are you shure @Turnipdabeets? My browser say no  as  0 == 0 is true and 0 == true is false and (0 == 0 == 0) is evaluated as false and (1 == 0 == 0) returns true. (Firefox)

Comment: Do not misunderstand me @Turnipdabeets, I appreciate your answer for pointing at bugs that can arise just changing the comparison operator. I just suggested some more case to show. [By the way, the Matched string is referred to a single index value of the array, not at the full structures, with an else branch this behaviour would be clearer]

Answer (score 2):

because.... thats the way boolean logic works.

By the way, you have one redundant check in your `if`.

if `a==b` and `b==c` then, by definition `a==c`

Answer (score 2):

The boolean logic which you're interpreting does not work like that. Your first logic is interpreted as: `(a[i] === b[i]) === c[i]`. That is why the newer is working!

Answer (score 2):

```js
a=[1,2,3],b=[1,2,3],c=[1,2,3];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (a[i] === b[i] === c[i]) {
     console.log("Matched")
    }
    else{
      console.log("error");
    }
 }
```

Explain : 
a[i] === b[i] // return boolean `true` or `false`

`true`|`false` === c[i] is `false`

Check the code. You can see the else part is running.

Also check the below code

```js
a=true,b=true,c=true;
if(a === b === c){
  console.log(a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your code:

**a[i] === b[i]** will execute first

it returns a Boolean value.
then compare this Boolean value with c ,like

**true === c**

of course it is false

write like this you can understand it better:

```
(a[i] === b[i])=== c[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it compares the first part then value is compared to next part.
You must try using inner bracket for the first part. Or do just like you did in second example.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
    (a[i]===(b[i]===c[i]))
    ((a[i]===b[i])===c[i])
```